# Context not being set properly with warbler and tomcat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jruby, jrubyonrails, warbler

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app to Tomcat with a war file generated by Warbler.  The war file deploys to /myproject-rails-gui without any problems but, when I try to access a page on the app, I'm getting:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
          send at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097
       Railtie at /home/myproject/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/webapps/myproject-rails-gui/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:54
```

It's failing when it tries to set relative_url_root.  There are other Stack Overflow articles that (correctly) point out that relative_url_root is deprecated and you should set the RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT environment variable instead.

From [the Rails project on GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.10/actionpack/lib/action_controller/deprecated/base.rb)

```
module ActionController
  class Base
    # Deprecated methods. Wrap them in a module so they can be overwritten by plugins
    # (like the verify method.)
    module DeprecatedBehavior #:nodoc:
      def relative_url_root
        ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "ActionController::Base.relative_url_root is ineffective. " <<
          "Please stop using it.", caller
      end

      def relative_url_root=
        ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "ActionController::Base.relative_url_root= is ineffective. " <<
          "Please stop using it.", caller
      end
```

I haven't had any luck figuring out how to do that using Warbler and Tomcat, though.  Any suggestions?  For what it's worth, the app works fine when I run it in the root context.

My environment:

- Warbler 1.3.2
- Tomcat 7.0.22
- JRuby 1.6.5
- Rails 3.0.10

Comment: I've also been able to get the same behavior using [trinidad](https://github.com/trinidad/trinidad).

Comment: Same problem here, with rails 3.1.1.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I've added `options.delete(:relative_url_root)` to **actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb** right before the line 54, where the error is occurring.